# Converting ODBC query results into XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, odbc

I'm trying to write a little C# console application that would run a query on an existing ODBC connection and converting the ResultSet into an XML file.  Could some please shed some light on this?

I was thinking to use the System.Xml.XmlReader to perform this task in the following context,

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "FIL=MS Access;DSN=valid data source name";
string query = "SELECT * FROM Customers FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS";

    try {
         OdbcCommand odbcComm = new OdbcCommand(query);
         conn.Open();
         odbcComm.Connection = conn;

         OdbcDataReader data = odbcComm.ExecuteReader();
                         .
                         .
                         .

    } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Console.WriteLine( "Failed to connect to the data source" );
    } finally {
            conn.Close();
    }
```

What do you think?

Comment: What have you got so far.. have you looked at xml serialization or at using Dataset ?

Comment: Is XmlReader a good object to look at?

Comment: yes I will place an example of what I have used but my example use a Web service so you can probably figure out a way to get the gist of what I am using by implementing your own solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done using a webservice.
I am not going to place the web service code here because of copy right crap from work.
but this code should give you an idea
basically create a method and make the node portion the return / results from that method and then from there use xmlnodeReader and from there what ever fields you need replace what I have in the DataTable and rows with your own fieldname values

```
XmlNode node = svc.GetInfoByZIP("02116");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(node))
    {
        ds.ReadXml(reader);
    }

    DataTable table = ds.Tables["Table"];
    DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
    string city = (string) row["CITY"];
    string state = (string) row["STATE"];
    string zip = (string) row["ZIP"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you want to do, although it's done with OleDB.  You can just ignore the OleDB connection code (replacing it with the ODBC equivalent) and focus on the part where the DataSet is being populated with data from the MS Access database by using a schema to format it to XML:

http://nathanbrixius.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/converting-an-access-db-to-xml-using-c/